# Django file creation error. Why do I get an attribute error: the 'bytes' object does not have the '_committed' attribute?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Actually, the error occurs when an entry in the database is trying to be created. It is not clear why the saved object is not perceived by the server as a File type, but if you print the type of this object, then it is a File, but the error says something else. The error occurs only on the server, everything works if I run it on my machine. The server is hosted on pythonanywhere.com.

```
Internal Server Error: /taskTest/1
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 84, in view
        return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 119, in dispatch
        return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/Bioni/Platon/main/views/student/task/taskUpload.py", line 35, in post
        self.createFiles(form, user.pk, task_id)
      File "/home/Bioni/Platon/main/views/student/task/taskUpload.py", line 46, in createFiles
        StudentFile.objects.create(creator=user_id, task_id=task_id, file=File(file))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
        return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 514, in create
        obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 806, in save
        self.save_base(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 857, in save_base
        updated = self._save_table(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1000, in _save_table
        results = self._do_insert(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1041, in _do_insert
        return manager._insert(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
        return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1434, in _insert
        return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1620, in execute_sql
        for sql, params in self.as_sql():
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1547, in as_sql
        value_rows = [
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1548, in <listcomp>
        [
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1549, in <listcomp>
        self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1497, in pre_save_val
        return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 314, in pre_save
        if file and not file._committed:
    AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute '_committed'
```

The view class below

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.files import File
from django.urls import reverse

from django.views import View

from main.forms import StudentTaskForm
from main.models import Task, StudentFile, UserTask, User, StudentGroup


class TaskUpload(View):
    def get(self, request, task_id):
        return render(request, "students/checkTask/task_upload.html", {'form': StudentTaskForm(), 'task_id': task_id})

    def post(self, request, task_id):
        form = StudentTaskForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = request.user
            task = Task.objects.filter(id=task_id).first()
            user = User.objects.filter(id=user.pk).first()
            stud_group = StudentGroup.objects.get(id=user.groups.first().pk)
            own_grade = form.cleaned_data['own_grade']
            currentUserTask = UserTask.objects.filter(user_id=user, main_task_id=task).first()

            if (currentUserTask == None):
                UserTask.objects.create(last_name=user.last_name, group_id=stud_group, first_name=user.first_name,
                                        user_id=user, main_task_id=task, own_grade=own_grade)
            else:
                currentUserTask.own_grade=own_grade
                currentUserTask.save()
                self.deleteFiles(task_id, user.pk)

            self.createFiles(form, user.pk, task_id)
            return JsonResponse({"url" : reverse("index")}, safe=False)
        else:
            form = StudentTaskForm()

        return render(request, "students/checkTask/task_upload.html", {'form': form, 'task_id': task_id})

    def createFiles(self, form, user_id, task_id):
        files = form.cleaned_data["files"]

        for file in files:
            StudentFile.objects.create(creator=user_id, task_id=task_id, file=File(file))

    def deleteFiles(self, task_id, user_id):
        files = StudentFile.objects.filter(task_id=task_id, creator=user_id)

        for file in files:
            file.delete()
```

Model

```
class StudentFile(models.Model):
    creator = models.IntegerField()
    task_id = models.IntegerField()
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="student_files/")

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        storage, path = self.file.storage, self.file.path
        super(StudentFile, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
        storage.delete(path)
```

Form

```
class StudentTaskForm(forms.Form):
    files = MultipleFileField()
    own_grade = forms.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.